# A tad confused about mapping virtual users to system users in Dovecot

Tags: email, dovecot

What I hope to do:

1. Use [getmail](http://pyropus.ca/software/getmail) to grab emails from several of my accounts (gmail, fastmail, Yahoo etc) ->
2. deliver to an instance of [Dovecot](https://wiki.dovecot.org) running locally ->
3. from which I'll use a mail client to access my emails

Sending isn't a goal for now.

**What I don't know**: how to map *account1@gmail.com* and *myveryoldaccount@yahoo.com* to *iain* the system account.

I'm looking at [virtual users](https://wiki.dovecot.org/VirtualUsers) but every discussion either mentions:

1. Postfix, which I'm not using (as yet)
2. Editing */etc/passwd*

Focussing on (2), I've already set up authentication via PAM and I'm not really interested in fiddling around with /etc/passwd. Is there not something available like?

```
# Some barely spoken about file
iain: account1@gmail.com, myveryoldaccount@yahoo.com

# dovecot.conf
address_mapping: use_barely_spoken_about_file
```

My *conf.d/auth-system.conf.ext* has the following (I'm not sure it's relevant or not):

```
passdb {
  driver = pam
  args = dovecot
}

userdb {
  # <doc/wiki/AuthDatabase.Passwd.txt>
  driver = passwd
  # [blocking=no]
  # see https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/SetupDovecot
  args = 
}
```

The Macports link has:

> Together, these prevent the need for hardcoded passwd.dovecot and
>   userdb.dovecot files, and don't require any knowledge of LDAP.
>   However, they only support system usernames, and not virtual
>   mailboxes. I have tested this with IMAP and the dovecot LDA (deliver)
>   successfully.

Should I simply replace getmail with Postfix? That seems like a lot of extra work, getmail is simple to setup.

Does the *barely_spoken_about_file* exist, or is it really */etc/passwd*?

Can I still authenticate via PAM?

Any help or insight, or just a nudge towards to right article would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're trying to map mailboxes that don't belong to your server in the first place? Is that something _getmail_ requires? (If it did, most people would have been unable to use it...)

Comment: Reading the getmail man oage I would be very surprised if getmail is deliverjng mail through dovecot - in fact I dont think dovecot supports this. I expect its simlly writing mail in a standard firnat and dovecot reads it.  This neans looking to dovecot is looking in the wrong place.

Comment: @davidgo getmail is acting as the Mail Retrieval Agent and Dovecot is acting as the Local Delivery agent. I can invoke getmail to deliver to a directory on my box but then messages are siloed and I lose the things that Dovecot can do, like filtering and funneling the messages to one receiver.

Comment: @grawity getmail will simply fetch mail given the address and account details. What I want is to take those disparate accounts and funnel them to one recipient who owns the accounts. I believe (because I've seen some articles where people do something similar but not quite, [for example](https://joel.porquet.org/wiki/hacking/getmail_dovecot/)) Dovecot should be able to take the messages from getmail and do this, but I'm not sure how to configure the mapping.

Comment: Ah, if it works anything like `fetchmail` used to, then I don't think you need to map these addresses as _accounts_ at all; getmail delivers everything via LDA to a single regular Dovecot account. Instead, I think you need to use Dovecot's Sieve module to filter/sort based on "Delivered-To:" or similar headers.

Comment: @grawity I see, I'll need to look into that then. Thanks for giving me a nudge in the right direction, much appreciated.